# Security exploits affecting login?

Tags: security, login-screen, password

On ubuntu 10.04, I choose System > Disconnect > Swich User, then at the login screen I can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to get a command line over a black screen, & then click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to redirect back to my password protected desktop WITHOUT entering password!

How is it possible and how can I fix it?

Comment: Update to Ubuntu 11.10 I would say. It should fix it right up.

Comment: should? Can you give me a SURE answer?

Comment: @Goldy I just verified in 11.10 switching back to F7 puts you at the locked screen.

Comment: Thanks marco. Are there ANYOTHER 'backdoors'?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "lock screen" instead. Switching the user doesn't log you out or lock the session, it just gives you a prompt to log in as someone else.

I just tried this in 11.04 and it still does it, and this is an intended feature I assume (abandoning or locking access to your terminal doesn't mean it will keep you logged out!), but it does have implications. I'd suggest [taking concerns to the bug tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) if you're worried about any of said implications.

Comment: I can't use "lock screen" because it aventualy freeze by desktop, & the only release is the "reset" button.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not on a newer version? Do you need the LTS?

Comment: Addenum: The only machine I have running 10.04 still is a server where I'd prefer to be on an LTS and minimize interruptions with distribution upgrades. Even if you don't like Unity, there are better options to that run newer and less buggy code.

Comment: I looks for a SERIOUS update; for some reasons it seems programmers change nothing... on ubuntu 8.10 they added a quick search window to Synaptic, & since then it's all the same.

Comment: Like the SERIOUS update that doesn't freeze when you lock the screen so you can be more secure? ;)